# ASP.NET Core 8 external login

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, .net-8.0

ASP.NET Core 8 RC2, Blazor web app template with individual accounts.
The register page links to an article regarding external login providers:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio

This provides examples for Google, Facebook, and Microsoft.

The problem is when I try to add this to the `program.cs`, `builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddGoogle`, `.AddMicrosoft`, etc. doesn't exist.

Does anybody know how to configure this for .NET 8?

Comment: I assume you need to install Nuget packages to it.

Comment: could you please install Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google,
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook,
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount NuGet packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Maytham mentions in the comments.

You need to install the respective Nuget package for each provider you're looking to add.

[image]

The package name for each provider is available on the respective instructions page here.  [Ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#setup-login-providers-required-by-your-application)

e.g. Facebook - [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook)

Comment: Haha, I totally missed that one line regarding the nuget package, that's embarassing 